# Row for pickerview titleForRow always start from 2

Tags: iphone, row, uipickerview, uipickerviewcontroller

I'm using UIpickerview in my app. The problem is that my `pickerview titleforrow` function always return 3 rows although `numberofRowsinComponent` return more rows.

```
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:
    (NSInteger)component {

return [filteredTerms count]; }


- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:
    (NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {


CreateOrder *order =  [filteredTerms objectAtIndex:row];

NSString *title;
title = order.kBranchName;

return title;   }
```

I've even tried to hard code the number or rows returned, but it is not working. The `titleforrow` row always start from 2.

Comment: How do you know it is starting at 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

return [filteredTerms objectAtIndex:row];

 }
```